# find_by_user_id_and_activity_id displaying only one record

Tags: activerecord, codeigniter-2

I have a table user

- id
- user_id
- activity_id
- status
  I need to display all the data with certain user_id and activity_id. I am trying

  User::find_by_user_id_and_activity_id('5', '11')

But it gives only one record.

How can I get all values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given much to go on but if using Rails 4, perhaps you can try to return one record:

```
User.find_by(user_id: 5, activity_id: 11)
```

or

```
User.where(user_id: 5, activity_id: 11) to return a collection.
```

Comment: does it return all records? or just single record?

Comment: can you explain how `find_by` answers this question?

Comment: whats the context here? I think `find_by` is wrong answer, agree?

Answer (score 1):

Please use following query to get all records with certain user_id and activity_id.

```
User.where(user_id: 5, activity_id: 11)
```

It give you an array of ActiveRecord::Relation.

> As per documaention of **find_by(args)**
>     Finds the first record
>   matching the specified conditions.
>   Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html